# How to get global_position of KinematicBody2D with sync_to_physics enabled?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot3

I have a node which has a child `KinematicBody2D` as such:

[image]

and the script of the `Holder` as such

```
extends Node2D

onready var item = $Item

func _physics_process(delta):
    global_position.y += 3000 * delta

func _draw():
    draw_line(
        to_local(item.global_position) - Vector2(100, 0),
        to_local(item.global_position) + Vector2(100, 0),
        Color.violet
    )
```

In theory, the `draw_line()` should draw at the position of the `Item` (green) but I'm guessing since `sync_to_physics` is enabled there is some offset due to catching up?

Regardless, the problem arises that the `global_position` being returned is wrong due to which the line being drawn is at the wrong position:

[image]

What's more bizarre is that when I resize the window it corrects itself:

[image]

So is there a reliable way / workaround I can get the `global_position` of a `KinematicBody2D` with sync_to_physics enabled?

**Edit:** A continuation of the question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78144928/area2d-not-detecting-bodies-when-moved-along-with-sync-to-physics-enabled-kinema)

Comment: Is this question still about `_draw`? Edit: this is the short check list to debug the earea: check you have not disabled monitoring in the area, check that the area collision mask has overlap with the kinematic body collision layer, check that the signal is connected, enable visible collision shapes form the debug menu, and you already have prints.

Comment: @Theraot Initially `_draw` was for verifying if the `global_position` while `sync_to_physics` enabled was returning the correct value, but using that same value doesn't work when I assign it to `Area2D`, Please let me know If you feel this should be a separate question I'll accept the solution and post a new question. Also yes I checked the all conditions in your debug list & to cross check I even initially placed the player in the Area2D and it did detect the player correctly

Comment: Is the `global_position` you are getting wrong? Why the area does not detect collisions seems to me a separate issue. You can try calling `force_update_transform` on the nodes after you move them.  I remember reading something about moving an area wouldn't detect collisions, but I can't find it right now. However, if it does not work, a workaround would be to use `intersect_shape` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the position correctly, and sync to physics is not the issue at hand either.

What happens is that Godot avoids calling `_draw` unless it knows it need to redraw. So once your `_draw` function ran, Godot won't call it  again unless something triggers it (resize the window, for example).

You can tell Godot to call `_draw` again by calling `queue_redraw()` in Godot 4, or `update` in Godot 3. For example:

```
extends Node2D

onready var item = $Item

func _physics_process(delta):
    global_position.y += 3000 * delta
    update()

func _draw():
    draw_line(
        to_local(item.global_position) - Vector2(100, 0),
        to_local(item.global_position) + Vector2(100, 0),
        Color.violet
    )
```

Comment: This works but when I try to use the same logic for setting the `global_position` of a child node it does for some reason, I've added it in the edit