# Area2D not detecting bodies when moved along with sync_to_physics enabled KinematicBody2D

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot3

A continuation of [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7S50l.png),

The solution provided there by @Theraot works for `_draw()` but not for `Area2D` as you can see in this example:

[image]

script for player:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity: Vector2

func _physics_process(_delta):
    velocity.y+=30
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

script for Holder:

```
extends Node2D

onready var item = $Item
onready var item_area = $ItemArea
onready var item_inital_offset = item.global_position - global_position
onready var area_inital_offset = item_area.global_position - item.global_position

var velocity: Vector2

func _body_entered(body):
    print("body_entered=>", body)

func _body_exited(body):
    print("body_exited=>", body)

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y+=30
    global_position+=velocity * delta
    
    item.global_position = global_position + item_inital_offset
    item_area.global_position = item.global_position + area_inital_offset

func _ready():
    item_area.connect("body_entered", self,"_body_entered")
    item_area.connect("body_exited", self,"_body_exited")
```

when the `Player` (green) falls into the `ItemArea` (blue) and stops when it hits `Item` (red), the `body_entered` signal is not emitted even though you can clearly see that it entered the area

[image]

I have checked that the `Area2D` node works by initially placing another body in it and it emits a signal just fine

my best guess is that maybe since both `Holder` & `Player` are both falling at the same speed they technically never intersect but since `Item` is synced_with_physics there's a visual lag which makes it drag back and *not* take the `ItemArea` along with it

---

**Edit**

I tried using `intersect_shape` directly within `Holder` but it still didn't work:

```
extends Node2D

onready var item = $Item
onready var item_inital_offset = item.global_position - global_position
const SHAPE_OFFSET = Vector2(0, -52)

export(Shape2D) var intersect_shape: Shape2D

var intersecting_bodies := {}
var velocity: Vector2

func _body_entered(body):
    print("body_entered=>", body)
func _body_exited(body):
    print("body_exited=>", body)
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y+=30
    global_position+=velocity * delta
    
    item.global_position = global_position + item_inital_offset
    
    check_area_process(delta)
    
    update()
func check_area_process(_delta):
    var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
    var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
    
    query.set_shape(intersect_shape)
    query.transform = item.global_transform
    query.transform.origin = item.global_position + SHAPE_OFFSET
    
    var currently_intersecting_nodes:Array = space.intersect_shape(query)
    var new_intersecting_bodies := {}
    
    # check for newly entered objects
    for node in currently_intersecting_nodes:
        node=node.collider
        new_intersecting_bodies[node]=null
        
        if(!intersecting_bodies.has(node)):
            _body_entered(node)
    
    # check for exited objects
    for node in intersecting_bodies:
        if(!new_intersecting_bodies.has(node)):
            _body_exited(node)
    
    intersecting_bodies=new_intersecting_bodies
func _draw():
    if(get_tree().debug_collisions_hint):
        draw_set_transform(to_local(item.global_position + SHAPE_OFFSET), 0, Vector2.ONE)
        intersect_shape.draw(get_canvas_item(), Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I remember an issue about areas not detecting bodies when they were moved. However, I have been unable to find it.*

We can use `force_update_transform` on the objects that moved (the body and the area). But - sadly - there isn't an equivalent to `force_raycast_update` for the area.

---

So, I'll go ahead and give you the solution without area.

We will work on your holder script, because there is where you want to use the area...

For ease of use, I'll say have these exports:

```
export(int, LAYERS_2D_PHYSICS) var collision_mask:int
export(Shape2D) var shape_2d:Shape2D
```

Then, in `_physics_process` you a `Physics2DDirectSpaceState` like this:

```
var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
```

Then you need to create a `Physics2DShapeQueryParameters` like this:

```
if shape_2d == null:
    return

var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
query.collision_layer = collision_mask
query.set_shape(shape_2d)
query.transform = global_transform
```

**Addendum**: I realize that you have the area offset from the holder, so you might want to compute an offset transformation for that. On a similar note, I remind you that the exported variables are for ease of use, but you can define those values in code if that makes more sense to you.

And then we can query what bodies are overlapping the shape:

```
if shape_2d == null:
    return

var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
query.collision_layer = collision_mask
query.set_shape(shape_2d)
query.transform = global_transform
currently_overlapping_bodies:Array = space.intersect_shape(query)
```

We can figure out what entered and what left... For that we need to add a variable on top (outside of `_physics_process`) to keep track of the overlapping bodies:

```
var overlapping_bodies:Array = []
```

And now, in `_physics_process` we can do this:

```
if shape_2d == null:
    return

var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
query.collision_layer = collision_mask
query.set_shape(shape_2d)
query.transform = global_transform

currently_overlapping_bodies:Array = space.intersect_shape(query)
exited:Array = []
entered:Array = []
for body in overlapping_bodies:
    if not body in currently_overlapping_bodies:
        exited.append(body)

for body in currently_overlapping_bodies:
    if not body in overlapping_bodies:
        entered.append(body)

overlapping_bodies = currently_overlapping_bodies
```

Be aware that since you wouldn't be using area anymore, it would not show up in the editor, nor while debugging with Visible Collision Shapes enabled. Thus, you need to use `_draw` to have some representation of it. Be aware that `Shape2D` has a `draw` method that you can use for this:

```
func _draw() -> void:
    if shape_2d == null or not get_tree().debug_collisions_hint:
        return

    shape_2d.draw(get_canvas_item())
```

**Addendum**: Since you might want to draw the shape offset, you might want to use `draw_set_transform`.

And, of course, remember to call `update`.

Comment: This works but only when I set the process_priority to -1, any idea why?

Comment: @M.R.M. In your answer, you made this inside of an area, while my intention was that you would not use an area at all. With this code running in a different node than the one that actually needs the result, the order in which the scripts are executed matters.

Comment: I tried running the code within the same node as you intended but it didn't work, I've added it to the edit

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Theroat's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78151473/22302305) I created a custom class which (somewhat) works when moving at high speeds, The only caveat is that it requires  `process_priority` to be set to a lower value (e.g. -1):

[image]

```
extends Area2D
class_name PreciseArea2D

const intersect_shape_color=Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5)

export(bool) var use_precision := false

var intersect_shape:Shape2D
var intersecting_bodies := {} # if `use_precision` is enabled

# intersect shape override methods
func get_overlapping_bodies():
    if(use_precision):
        return intersecting_bodies.keys()
    else:
        return .get_overlapping_bodies()
func overlaps_body(body:Node):
    if(use_precision):
        return intersecting_bodies.has(body)
    else:
        return .overlaps_body(body)

# virtual methods
func _process(_delta):
    update()
func _physics_process(_delta):
    var space := get_world_2d().direct_space_state
    var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
    
    query.set_shape(intersect_shape)
    query.collision_layer = collision_layer
    query.transform = global_transform
    
    var currently_intersecting_nodes:Array = space.intersect_shape(query)
    var new_intersecting_bodies := {}
    
    
    # check for newly entered objects
    for node in currently_intersecting_nodes:
        node=node.collider
        new_intersecting_bodies[node]=null
        
        if(!intersecting_bodies.has(node)):
            emit_signal("body_entered", node)
    
    # check for exited objects
    for item in intersecting_bodies:
        if(!new_intersecting_bodies.has(item)):
            emit_signal("body_exited", item)
    
    intersecting_bodies=new_intersecting_bodies
func _draw():
    if(use_precision and get_tree().debug_collisions_hint):
        intersect_shape.draw(get_canvas_item(), intersect_shape_color)
func _ready():
    if(use_precision):
        
        for child in get_children():
            if(child is CollisionShape2D):
                intersect_shape = child.shape
                child.queue_free()
        
        process_priority=-1 # not sure why
        set_physics_process(true)
        set_process(true)
    else:
        set_physics_process(false)
        set_process(false)
```